# Why is there no guarantee that a linear combination of generic nondegenerate bilinear forms is still non degenerate?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-bundles

Why is there no guarantee that a linear combination of generic nondegenerate bilinear forms is still non degenerate? Is there an example for that?

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789402/why-arent-complex-vector-bundles-isomorphic-to-their-duals) there is a claim that a linear combination of generic nondegenerate bilinear forms is still non degenerate if these nondegenerate bilinear forms are positive definite. Is there any reference to illustrate this claim or can you give a proof for this claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is there no guarantee that a linear combination of generic nondegenerate bilinear forms is still non degenerate? Is there an example for that?

$I$ is non-degenerate, but $0=I-I$ is degenerate.

> From here there is a claim that a linear combination of generic nondegenerate bilinear forms is still non degenerate if these nondegenerate bilinear forms are positive definite.

It's false. What is true is that a *positive* combination of positive definite bilinear forms is positive definite.

Comment: How about a positive linear combination of generic non degenerate complex bilinear forms? Is that still possible to be degenerate?

Comment: @Danny $0=I+(-I)$ is a positive combination of non-degenerate bilinear forms.