# Why my proof is wrong(complex vector bundle$E\cong E^*$)

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

This might be a simple question,but I wonder where I did wrong.I have seen this:  [Why aren't complex vector bundles isomorphic to their duals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789402/why-arent-complex-vector-bundles-isomorphic-to-their-duals?noredirect=1&lq=1)  .

Let $E$ be a complex vector bundle with an hermitian structure $h$,we know that as real bundles,we have $E\cong E^*$.However,as complex vector bundles,it is incorrect in general.

But we always have $\overline E\cong E^*$.Here is the proof:since $h(v,w)$ is linear in $v$ and antilinear in $w$,the map $w\longmapsto h(\cdot,w)$ defines an isomorphism from $\overline E$ to $E^*$.

Then,if I define $v\longmapsto h(v,\cdot)$,isn't it an isomorphismfrom $E$ to $E^*$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But $h(v,\,\cdot\,)$ isn't linear, it's antilinear.

Comment: @DanielFischer,thanks for your comment!I forgot $h(v,\cdot)\not\in E^*$.